# Weighted addition in c++

Tags: c++

Adding two arrays element by element and save the result to the first array can be achieved by the following code (compiled with c++14):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::array<double,3> a = {1, 2, 3};
    std::array<double,3> b = {4, 5, 6};
    std::transform(a.begin( ), a.end( ), b.begin( ), a.begin( ),std::plus<double>( ));

    for(double d : a)
        std::cout << d << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

That is

```
a[i] = a[i] + b[i]
```

What if I want to get the followings? Is it still possible done by std::transform or any other functionality in std algorithm?

```
a[i] = a[i] * weight + b[i] * (1. - weight)
```

Thanks a lot...

Comment: Use a lambda and define the functionality in the lambda body.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The traditional way would be a stateful functor.  These days we can just do it with a lambda:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::array<double,3> a = {1, 2, 3};
    std::array<double,3> b = {4, 5, 6};
    const double weight = 0.7;

    std::transform(a.begin( ), a.end( ), b.begin( ), a.begin( ),
             [weight](double aa, double bb) {
                 return aa*weight + bb*(1. - weight);
             }
    );

    for(double d : a)
        std::cout << d << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

As requested, the old way:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

struct weighted_add {
    const double weight;
    double operator() const (double aa, double bb) {
        return aa*weight + bb*(1.-weight);
    }
    weighted_add(double weight_) : weight(weight_) {}
};

int main()
{
    std::array<double,3> a = {1, 2, 3};
    std::array<double,3> b = {4, 5, 6};

    std::transform(a.begin( ), a.end( ), b.begin( ), a.begin( ), weighted_add(0.7));

    for(double d : a)
        std::cout << d << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

(Note: none of this code has seen a compiler.  Beware errors).

Comment: Please give example of "stateful functor".  This will allow comparison between the techniques. (IMO, lambdas are difficult to read.)

Comment: The trouble with functors is that they involve defining the class outside the function - which means separating the line of code from its use.

Comment: @GillBates: Much too late for that.  Functor is the accepted term in C++.  Slightly sad, but it's how it is.

Answer (score 3):

A non-lambda solution (compatible with C++03) would be:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

struct MyFunctor
{
    const double _weight;
    MyFunctor(double weight) : _weight(weight) {}
    double operator()(double a, double b) const
    {
        return a * _weight + b * (1. - _weight);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::array<double,3> a = {1, 2, 3};
    std::array<double,3> b = {4, 5, 6};
    double weight = 0.7;
    std::transform(a.begin( ), a.end( ), b.begin( ), a.begin( ), MyFunctor(weight));

    for(double d : a)
        std::cout << d << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bother.  Your answer and my edit crossed in the ether.

Comment: @MartinBonner :)